# (Catholic view) Why do we pray for God's Kingdom to come if good people go to heaven when they die?

Tags: catholicism, heaven, kingdom-of-god

Here I wanted to find the Catholic view as to why we are told, e.g. in [the Lord's Prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord's_Prayer#Second_Petition) (from [Matthew 6:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%206%3A10&version=NRSVCE)) to pray for God's Kingdom to come when, on another hand, our immortal soul will end up in heaven (if we have been considered "good") when we die.

What is the purpose of God's Kingdom to come when the faithful anyway end up in heaven and the rest end in hell? What do we need the Kingdom for in this case?

Comment: Because it's about God's kingdom coming *to earth*, not just heaven. It's right there in the verse you cited!

Comment: where did you learn you go to heaven if you've been considered "good"? That's not a Catholic teaching. You must be in a state of grace. And that's the Kingdom of God in our life when the Trinity comes to reside in your heart and you become the temple of the HS.

Comment: Thanks, @Grasper, for sharing that.  It's something I'd not understood about Catholicism before and I appreciate it.

Comment: the bible says "There is none who does good, no, not one" (rom 3) Also, Jesus said in john 3:3  "Most assuredly I say to you, unless a man be born again, he cannot see the Kingdom of God". I would recommend reading the book of John! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What is a kingdom? It is primarily a king and his subjects, and only secondarily about a territory that is possessed. When you pray for the Kingdom to come:

1) You are asking for the King to come.

2) You are probing for any source of rebellion against that King in your heart and praying for a change of heart that it might cease.

3) You are praying that God will cause that kingdom to grow in extent by converting more rebels to the cause.

4) You are consenting to be an agent of the King to assist in accomplishing that goal.

5) You are praying that those in rebellion fail in their attempts to persuade loyal subjects to rebel.

6) You are praying that this process begin right now, while you ands those for whom you pray still live, instead of waiting until it is too late to change your mind and behavior.

Luke 17 says:

> nor will they say, ‘Look, here it is!’ or ‘There!’ for behold, the
>   kingdom of God is in the midst of you.”

Before you can get into the kingdom, you need for the kingdom to get into you.

Answer (score 0):

> The Kingdom of God lies ahead of us. It is brought near in the Word
>   incarnate, it is proclaimed throughout the whole Gospel, and it has
>   come in Christ's death and Resurrection. The Kingdom of God has been
>   coming since the Last Supper and, in the Eucharist, it is in our
>   midst. The kingdom will come in glory when Christ hands it over to his
>   Father:
>
> *It may even be . . . that the Kingdom of God means Christ himself,
>   whom we daily desire to come, and whose coming we wish to be
>   manifested quickly to us. For as he is our resurrection, since in him
>   we rise, so he can also be understood as the Kingdom of God, for in
>   him we shall reign.86*

And specifically:

> In the Lord's Prayer, "thy kingdom come" refers primarily to the
>   final coming of the reign of God through Christ's return. 88 But, far
>   from distracting the Church from her mission in this present world,
>   this desire commits her to it all the more strongly.

[Source](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p4s2a3.htm)